# Animating large image doesn't work properly on Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-animations

I have a large, wide image I'm animating using CSS. The image is displayed and animated as expected on Chrome (Both desktop & on Android) and Firefox.

However, on Safari (Both desktop & mobile, v12.1), the image is usually not being animated, or worse - shown partly/not being shown at all - on the initial load. After one or two page refreshes it begins to behave as expected (probably because it loads the image from the cache).

After disabling the animation, the image is displayed fine on the initial load.

[Demo](https://17874ky44.codesandbox.io/)
[Source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/17874ky44)

Any ideas why Safari behaves like that?

Comment: Tested it on Safari 12.1 myself on my Macbook, but seems to work just fine?

Comment: Make sure to open the inspector and on the network tab, disable the cache (the icon next to the trash bin). Also empty the caches (Develop > Empty Caches). For me, it loads the image properly but not animating it (iOS behaves differently, more quirky).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up loading the image through JavaScript which made it show up and animate properly on Safari. This does not solve the source of the problem but works fine as a temporary fix.

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
const image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
  imageElement.src = image.src;
  imageElement.className = 'animation-class-name';
};
image.src = 'pic.jpg';
```